# Missing return type on function in Jest / eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, jestjs

I have this Jest in my project

```
const action = async () => {
                await hotelService.getByIdAsync(Identifier);
};

await expect(action()).rejects.toThrowError(FunctionalError);
```

but I have this eslint error

```
 92:28  error  Missing return type on function  @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
```

Comment: action function is not returning anything, hence the error as you are expecting it to throw error.

Comment: What is unclear from the ESLint message? Did you read the rule's guidance? Note you may want to use different, more permissive linting rules for your tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the return type of the function. As function is `async`, it returns a `Promise` wrapped around the data returned by `hotelService.getByIdAsync(Identifier)`

```
const action = async (): Promise</*type of data wrapped in promise*/> => {
   return await hotelService.getByIdAsync(Identifier);
};
```

Comment: I got the error "TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value"

Comment: add a `return` keyword before `await`

Comment: This alters the behaviour of the function though - it *did not* return any value before :)

Comment: @eol `async` functions always return a `Promise`, whether you write the `return` statement or not

Comment: sure, but it is a void Promise in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The `action` function does not specify a return type, hence the error. In order to get rid of the linting error, you need to set the return type to `Promise<void>` as the function is async and thus just returns a resolved promise without an actual value:

```
const action = async () : Promise<void> => {
    await hotelService.getByIdAsync(Identifier);
};
```